# commander.js : how to specify required cli argument

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, required-field, node-commander

I'm using commander.js package for parsing command-line arguments: I'd like to make a flag non-optional, the API and tests in the [git repo](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js) loosely mention making a flag required, but I usually need to be hit over the head with instructions.

Is it actually possible, and will the script throw if the requirement is not met?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess this is not supported by commander.js https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/issues/44

But you can do something like this in your program -

```
if (!program.myoption) 
  throw new Error('--myoption required')
```

Comment: commander has `program.requiredOption()` to flag an option as required now.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you write the arguments.

- With `<>` it is required.
- With `[]` it is not required.

See exemple.

```
const commander = require('commander')
    , program = new commander.Command()

program
   .command('autorecord')
   .argument('<title>', 'Title and file name of record') // is required
   .argument('[type]', 'Type of record. "undefined" by default') // is not required
```